# Using Courier New font when main language uses cyrillic script

Tags: fonts, polyglossia, cyrillic

If I set language that uses cyrillic script as the default one, I can't use font `Courier New`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
\texttt{русский язык}
\end{document}
```

The compiler is complaining:
`! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrillic script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.`

But, as you can see, `Courier New` is defined with `\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Courier New}`.

I compile with XeLaTeX.

Edit: `polyglossia` package is required.

Comment: Maybe you can do an advanced search of some sorts in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/. I've never used the catalogue, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
\begin{document}
\texttt{русский язык}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`polyglossia` is strict about scripts in fonts. So if a font doesn't have Cyrillic script defined, it won't allow you to use it. Particularly for Courier New:

```
% otfinfo -s Courier_New.ttf
arab            Arabic
arab.URD        Arabic/Urdu
hebr            Hebrew
latn            Latin
latn.LTH        Latin/Lithuanian
latn.ROM        Latin/Romanian
```

`babel` on the other hand doesn't bother about scripts, it just requires Cyrillic characters to be in place. The following code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
\texttt{русский язык}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need `polyglossia` (I think I don't need to explain why, since those reasons are irrelevant for this problem). I planned to use `Courier New` for code only (therefore no cyrillic script inside of `\texttt{}`, only latin, dismiss `\texttt{русский язык}`, it's just an example). But that's not possible either. So, if any of you know any other good font for code that supports cyrillic script, please recommend it as a replacement for `Courier New`.

Comment: You could switch to English for code snippets. Something like `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textenglish{\texttt{#1}}}`.

Comment: I tried `\textenglish{\texttt{TEST}}` but compiler says `Undefined control sequence.`  `l.8 \textenglish{\texttt{TEST}}`.

Comment: You'd have to add `\setotherlanguage{english}` to the preamble to define `\textenglish`. Unfortunately, Polyglossia still complains about Cyrillic script. So sorry, this doesn't work either.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to have text in some code format in my document?